# Initialize django CheckboxSelectMultiple with everything unchecked?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a model form that is rendering a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` as a `CheckboxSelectMultiple`

```
class VisitForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VisitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if queryset:
            self.fields['students'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=queryset,
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
            )
```

It's rendered very simply in the template right now:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{field.label}}
    {{field}}
</div>
```

It initializes okay with the selections I expect to be there - but by default both options are `checked`

I am trying to figure out how to intialize the boxes so they are `unchecked` by default.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

It's initialized in the `view` like this:

```
visitor = Visitor.objects.get(unique_id=unique_id)
students = Student.objects.filter(parents__unique_id=unique_id)
form = VisitForm(initial={'visitor':visitor, 'students':students}, queryset=students)
```

Comment: Try removing `'students':students` from your `initial` data.

Comment: That worked, I can't believe I overlooked that little thing. Whoops!

Comment: @Alasdair is right, you should not put values to `initial `on the field if you want it `unchecked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `students` queryset as the initial data, so Django selects every student in the queryset.

You could use an empty queryset `Student.objects.none()`, but it is even easier to remove `students` from the `initial` dictionary:

```
form = VisitForm(initial={'visitor':visitor}, queryset=students)
```